# How to put api in the folder of main site

Tags: flutter, api, iis

I have Flutter Website in IIS 10 and I want to put my API to the same domain in the "API" folder
how do I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, right click your website - Add web application

[image]

Second, name the alias as "API" ,choose the path as your api application folder.
[image]

Then, visit "domain/API" will be your API content. Such as there is a "weatherforecast" route in my testAPI.
[image]

Comment: I appreciate your answer.